# Count of dates by a certain variables in R

Tags: r, date, count

What I have:

**DF1**

| App | Proc | Rej | Old |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-11 | 2021-05-11 | NA | NA |
| 2021-05-11 | 2021-05-11 | NA | NA |
| 2021-05-11 | NA | NA | NA |
| 2021-05-11 | 2021-05-11 | NA | NA |
| 2021-05-12 | 2021-05-12 | NA | 2021-09-12 |
| 2021-05-12 | 2021-05-12 | 2021-10-01 | NA |
| 2021-05-13 | 2021-05-13 | NA | 2021-09-12 |
| 2021-05-13 | 2021-05-13 | 2021-10-01 | NA |
| 2021-05-13 | 2021-05-13 | 2021-10-01 | NA |
| 2021-05-13 | NA | NA | NA |
| 2021-05-13 | 2021-05-13 | NA | 2021-09-12 |
| 2021-05-13 | NA | NA | NA |
| 2021-05-13 | 2021-05-13 | NA | NA |

What I want: A new table with count of App and New by Dates. Ignoring Old and Rej

DFdesired:

| Date | App | Proc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-11 | 4 | 3 |
| 2021-05-12 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021-05-13 | 7 | 5 |

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(dplyr , warn.conflicts = F)

DF1 |> group_by(App) |> summarise(app = n()) -> df2
DF1 |> group_by(Proc) |> summarise(proc =n()) -> df3

df2  |>  left_join(df3 , by = c("App" = "Proc")) -> DFdesired
```

**Output**

```
DFdesired

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  App          app  proc
  <chr>      <int> <int>
1 2021-05-11     4     3
2 2021-05-12     2     2
3 2021-05-13     7     5
```

Comment: Hi, I edited New to Proc in Dfdesired. That was a mistake on my end. This code only creates a table of aggregates for approved with not corresponding dates.

Comment: Still not working. Outputs a table of just frequencies of approved

Comment: Is the output is your DFdesired ? or you have error in code .

Comment: DFdesired is what I would like. The code you have provided only gives me Approved. Not column for date or proc is outputted.

Comment: The output in my machine is like above , would you `dput(head(DF1))`

Comment: > dput(head(df2))
structure(list(Approved = c(4L, 2L, 10L, 21L, 21L, 8L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`. You can select the `App` and `Proc` columns for pivoting, and remove rows where `NA` is the value.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(App, Proc), values_drop_na = T) %>%
  count(value, name) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = value, names_from = name, values_from = n)
```

**Output**

```
  value        App  Proc
  <chr>      <int> <int>
1 2021-05-11     4     3
2 2021-05-12     2     2
3 2021-05-13     7     5
```